# align div to bottom: Am I using "align-content-end" incorrectly?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm new to BootStrap (and pretty new to web development) and have been going through a lot of video tutorials and the docs but I'm still wrestling with layout – I'm not getting something.

What I am trying to do below is create left and right panels which will hold other content not shown, and have the yellow and green button bars align to the bottom of the container, no matter what other content is in the panels.

I've been poking at this for a few hours now. Am I fundamentally laying this out incorrectly or am I not using the `align-content-end` class in the right place?

*(I don't know why the snippet below is throwing an error – it seems to work)*

---

What I have:

[image]

---

What I want:

[image]

```css
#events-tab-container {
  /* background: gray; */
  height: 90vh;
}

#left-panel {
  background: lightcoral;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* margin-right: 10px; */
}

#right-panel {
  background: lightskyblue;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#button-bar-left {
  background: yellow;
}

#button-bar-right {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="events-tab-container" class="container">
  <div class="row h-100">

    <div id="left-panel" class="col col-8">
      left

      <div id="button-bar-left" class="row d-flex justify-content-end align-content-end">
        <button id="cancel-event-btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary mr-2">Cancel</button>
        <button id="save-event-btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2">Save Event</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="right-panel" class="col col-4">

      right

      <div id="button-bar-right" class="row d-flex justify-content-end align-content-end">
        <button id="new-event-btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2">New Event</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- END EVENTS CONTAINER -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the cols `d-flex flex-column` and then `mt-auto` for auto top margins...

```
<div id="events-tab-container" class="container">
    <div class="row h-100">

        <div id="left-panel" class="col col-8 d-flex flex-column">
            left

            <div id="button-bar-left" class="d-flex mt-auto justify-content-end align-content-end">
                <button id="cancel-event-btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary mr-2">Cancel</button>
                <button id="save-event-btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2">Save Event</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="right-panel" class="col col-4 d-flex flex-column">

            right

            <div id="button-bar-right" class="d-flex flex-column mt-auto justify-content-end align-items-end">
                <button id="new-event-btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2">New Event</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/UGWsZZA4rB

Comment: thanks! that got me moving again. Looks like I need to study up on Flexbox some more.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the parent of the bars `display: flex` in-order to use its all its fun properties.

Example with flex:

```
.left-panel {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Then you'll need to add margin to the bar itself to sit where you want it.